# Auto increment version when pulishing Azure Service Fabric from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure-service-fabric

Is there a way how to auto increment version when publishing to Azure Service Fabric from Visual Studio? It's annoying to set that manually everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure [Application Debug Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-manage-application-in-visual-studio) - `Remove Application`. This way your existing application will be freshly installed every time you run the debugger (and removed when the debugging stops). Then there's no need to change the version numbers.

Comment: Thanks, @LoekD, this can be useful in some scenarios. But in others I need only to update the application and not to remove it after debbuging stops.